# How do I create a Dataframe_new in python from an existing Dataframe_old.

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, pivot-table

My apologies in advanced if this type of question exists, I am very new to stack overflow, I tried my best to see if this question has been answered already.

To give you some context. I have a test with 100 images of hands, each image has the same set of possible answers to select from. eg:

> - how many scars can you identify on the hand...... s0 / s1 / s2 / s3+
> - which fingernail is in the worst condition .... f1/f2/f3/f4/f5
> - which finger is missing..... mf0/mf1/mf2/mf3/mf4/mf5

Each possible answer per image is unique. All the answers are exported to a csv file and imported into Python using pd.read_csv to import it into Dataframe_old.  It looks like this.

> user_id | question_id | scars | fingernail | missing_fin

with the respective data values.

> 1015 | 1 | s2 | f5 | mf0
>
> 1016 | 1 | s2 | f3 | mf0
>
> 1017 | 1 | s2 | f5 | mf0
>
> 1015 | 2 | s1 | f1 | mf1
>
> 1016 | 2 | s1 | f1 | mf1
>
> 1017 | 2 | s2 | f2 | mf1

I am wanting the Dataframe_new to reflect something like this.

> question_id | s0 | s1 | s2 | s3| s3+ | f1 | f2 | f3 | f4 | f5 | mf0 | mf1 | mf2 | mf3 | mf4 | mf5

the data values would be the count of each answer per question for all 100 questions/images. eg. question 1, 50 users answered s0, 20 users answered s2 and one user answer s3+.  Question 2, all 71 user answered s0

> 1 | 50 | 0 | 20 | 0 | 1
>
> 2 | 71 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0

I tried reading up on a pandas.pivot_table but I came nowhere close. I think I need to iterate over each cell in the data field in Dataframe_old and where it sees a value, check if the column exists in Dataframe_new, if not use the data value as the column label and count 1.

I could easily be over complicating this but I have very little experience and so eager to learn.
I don't expect anyone to give me the solution, even if someone could just point me in the right direction or advise me on a better way I should be doing this. or packages in python that I can read up on.

I have spend copious amounts of time on the internet trying to figure this out but I think im googling the wrong questions.

Thanks Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create [dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) of the variables and then group the data by `question_id` and sum up the columns:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/stackoverflow_data.tsv', sep='\t')

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   user_id  question_id scars fingernail missing_fin
0     1015            1    s2         f5         mf0
1     1016            1    s2         f3         mf0
2     1017            1    s2         f5         mf0
3     1015            2    s1         f1         mf1
4     1016            2    s1         f1         mf1
5     1017            2    s2         f2         mf1

In [4]: df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['scars', 'fingernail', 'missing_fin'])

In [5]: df.drop('user_id', axis=1, inplace=True)

In [6]: df_new = df.groupby('question_id').sum(axis=0)

In [7]: df_new
Out[7]: 
             scars_s1  scars_s2  fingernail_f1  fingernail_f2  fingernail_f3  \
question_id                                                                    
1                   0         3              0              0              1   
2                   2         1              2              1              0   

             fingernail_f5  missing_fin_mf0  missing_fin_mf1  
question_id                                                   
1                        2                3                0  
2                        0                0                3
```

Comment: Thank you so much Benjamin, this is exactly what I was referring too.  You have given me a new way to look at this and similar problems. Im not sure how to upvote your comment.